# "IEDriverServer does not exist" error during running Selenium test with C# in Windows 7

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I'm working on Automation framework using WebDriver with C#. Its working fine with Firefox but not with IE.

I am getting the following error:

> IEDriverServer.exe does not exist-The file c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\TestProject1\TestProject1\bin\Debug\IEDriverServer.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

I am using IE 9 and Windows 7.

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");
IWebElement queryBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
queryBox.SendKeys("The Automated Tester");
queryBox.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);
queryBox.Submit();
```

See also [image: this screenshot].

Comment: Simply copy it to the output directory Bin\Debug if it not already there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per Jim Evans (who works on IEDriverServer)

> The .NET bindings don't scan the %PATH% environment variable for the
> executable. That means for the .NET bindings *only*, the
> IEDriverServer.exe is expected to either be found in the same
> directory as the .NET bindings assembly, or you must specify the
> directory where it can be found in the constructor to the
> InternetExplorerDriver class.
>
> Failure to do one of these things (or to
> set the UseInternalServer property in the InternetExplorerOptions
> class) will cause the .NET IE driver implementation to throw an
> exception. This is strictly by design, as we want people to begin
> using the standalone IEDriverServer.exe, and the ability to use an
> "internal" or "legacy" version of the server will be removed in a
> future release.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/webdriver/EvTyEPYchxE

Comment: Can u help me with the code sample how to bind IEDriverServer.exe using c#.Is it this way 
                    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.ie.driver", "D://Software//IEDriverServer.exe");
                    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

Comment: I haven't worked in C# bindings. However one way to resolve this outside code is, to pass this variable while starting selenium jar. Like java -jar selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="D://Software//IEDriverServer.exe"

Comment: There are now unofficial NuGet packages for [Chrome](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/) and [IE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver/); these add the drivers to your packages directory, add links in your test project to them, & set to "copy if newer." Then just call the constructor overloads, passing "." for the current directory *(due to the %PATH% issue above)*; ex: `ScenarioContext.Current["browser"] = new ChromeDriver(".");` With [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) I didn't need to configure it to copy the files either.

Comment: This worked for me: `java -jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\IEDriverServer.exe" selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register`. Please note that `-Dwebdriver.ie.driver` comes immediately after `java -jar`.

Answer (score 22):

The IEDriverServer.exe (as well as ChromeDriver.exe) can be downloaded from:

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

To get these to work with your Selenium tests, include the .exe in your test project, and set its properties to 'Copy Always'.

NOTE: You'll have to adjust the Add File dialog to display .exe files.

Doing this will resolve the error.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple C# example of how to call the `InternetExplorerDriver` using the IEDriverServer.exe.

Refactor according to your needs.

**Note:** the use of `driver.Quit()` which ensures that the IEDriverServer.exe process is closed, after the test has finished.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class IEDriverTest
    {
        private const string URL = "http://url";
        private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\PathTo\IEDriverServer.exe";

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            var options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
            {
                InitialBrowserUrl = URL,
                IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
            };
            var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);
            driver.Navigate();
            driver.Close(); // closes browser
            driver.Quit(); // closes IEDriverServer process
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Visual Studio and C# I've updated my NareshScaler nuget package to install IEDriverServer, ChromeDriver etc automatically, meaning you can get up and running quicker.

http://nuget.org/packages/NareshScaler

Comment: Can you help me to do it without using NareshScaler package using c# code

Answer (score 1):

Code for WebDriver using java to run with IE. I believe this concept might be helpful for you using C#:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);      
File file = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

If above code doesn't work use the following instead of "File file = new File("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");":

```
File file = new File("F:\\Ripon\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.2\\IEDriverServer.exe");
```

[Note: The version of IEDriverServer and Windows (32 or 64 bit) may vary individual to individual]

Comment: I downloaded "IEDriverServer_Win32_2.31.0.zip". According to your guide it's working well. Thanks Ripon

Comment: @user2027659: It's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Give path only till folder where Internetexplorer.exe is located.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using System.IO;

namespace Automation
  {
    class To_Run_IE
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         //Keep Internetexplorer.exe in "D:\Automation\32\Internetexplorer.exe"
          IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"D:\Automation\32\"); \\Give path till the exe folder
         //IWebDriver driver = new Firefoxdriver()
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
       driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();         
       IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
       query.SendKeys("Cheese");        
       query.Submit();         
       System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);
       driver.Quit();
    }
} }
```

Comment: Hi Nithin and welcome to the site. Could you consider expanding on your answer a little to make it more complete? There's a guide to good answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - generally we prefer a little more explanation than a one-line answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public IWebDriver IEWebDriver()
    {
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
        webDriver = new   InternetExplorerDriver(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["IDEServerPath"].ToString(), options);//Path of ur IE WebDriver,Here I stored it in a AppConfig File
        return webDriver;
   }
```